# Bibliography style need

Tags: bibliographies

I need the reference style for my thesis given by:
H.E. Exner, “Physical and Chemical Nature of Cemented Carbides,” International
Metals Review, 24(1979)149-173.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you just describe your desired bibliography style and add an image of it. I don't know if everyone has access to your mentioned article.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand correctly: Do you mean to say you need to use the same bibliography citation style as used in the paper you cite or do you just give this reference as an example of what you would like the output to be? In the first case it would be great if you could spare people having to look up the article and could describe in your question directly and explicitly what you need. In the second case I'm afraid that one example of an `@article` entry isn't quite enough to write a complete style.

Comment: I also note that you tagged your question with `biblatex`. `biblatex` is a specific bibliography package that does not use classical BibTeX and its `.bst` styles. Are you sure you want to (and can) use `biblatex` or do you want to use BibTeX?

Comment: I am using Jabref for bibliography and I need bibliography style like: [1] H.E. Exner, “Physical and Chemical Nature of Cemented Carbides,” International Metals Review, 24(1979)149-173. (For journal)       [2] R.M. German, Powder Injection Molding, Metal Powder Industries Federation, Princeton, NJ, USA, 1990. (for Book) [3] H.F. Fischmeister, “Development and Present Status of the Science and Technology of
Hard Materials,” Science of Hard Materials, R.K. Viswanadham, D.J. Rowcliffe, and J. Gurland (eds.), Plenum Press, New York, NY, USA, 1982, pp. 1-45.(Conference Proceedings) [4]

Comment: Please edit your question with that clarification. Note that JabRef is just a tool to produce `.bib` files, it does not commit you to using either `biblatex` or classical BibTeX (but it has different modes for the two). So the question whether or not you actually want to use `biblatex` is still open.

Comment: I need bibliography style like: [1] H.E. Exner, “Physical and Chemical Nature of Cemented Carbides,” International Metals Review, 24(1979)149-173. (For journal) [2] R.M. German, Powder Injection Molding, Metal Powder Industries Federation, Princeton, NJ, USA, 1990. (for Book)              Is it to possible to find above style by changing bibliographystyle in \bibliographystyle{apalike}?